# How to make a window you can't exit with any python module?

Tags: python, module, pygame

I'm trying to make a classroom manager that can allow teachers to control the students' device during lesson.(Temporarily displaying a window to 'lock' the screen of the student when the teacher is talking)
I need to make a window that will automatically open in fullscreen when the teacher presses a button. However, making a window students can't exit was what I have been truggling with.
I cantry to use `pygame.set_mode(... pygame.FULLSCREEN)` But the user can overide by `Alt`-`F4` or `Ctr`-`Alt`-`del`

Comment: What you're looking to do interferes with how the operating system normally works. Depending on what OS you're using, there will be ways to do what you want, but you'll likely need to make some specific API calls to the OS (so you'd need an appropriate package or module that allows you to do it) - a good starting point would be to look for writing Python applications in "kiosk mode" (that's what you're trying to do is often called)

Comment: So what if I have 2 windows, 1 to be a back up so that it will open another one when it detects `Alt`-`f4`

Comment: Also, how does family link manager by Google work? (As in how does it make an unescapable window to stop the child from using the phone after a specific time)

Comment: Software like that taps into functionality of the OS (Android in that case) itself. I wouldn't be able to tell you what functionality family link offers directly, but parental controls are built into the OS, and the app just uses that directly. Whether you'd be able to build anything that works just like it is not a given - however, I was assuming you were talking about Windows, or other common desktop OSes?

Comment: Ok thanks, I know understand. (I'm trying to support all OS but now I see that that seems impossible) Pls put your comment as an answer and I will accept it and close this question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found something equivalent to what I'm trying to achieve:
in pygame just override the quit event by doing nothing!
so replace

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
```

with

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pass
```

which does nothing when quit occurs.
In PyQt:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget): # or QMainWindow
    ...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # do stuff
        if can_exit:
            event.accept() # let the window close
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

And in Tkinter change:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox as messagebox
root = tk.Tk()

def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        root.destroy()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.mainloop()
```

To:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox as messagebox
root = tk.Tk()

def on_closing():
    pass

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.mainloop()
```

I may have also forgotten to mention that the targeted audiences have managed devices with a policy enabled not allowing students to use task managers.

Comment: Thanks to those who gave me advice. Really appreciated it.